# Routing example.com to a static file but example.com/anything to something else in Express-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am new to Parse and I am trying to deploy my app to, say, `example.com`.

I want `example.com` to serve a static landing page, but `example.com/anything` (of course, `anything` is NOT a literal, it can be anything) to be handled by another controller.

To make it more clear:

Scenario 1: User types `www.example.com` in their web browser.

Output: My static landing page, say, `index.html`

Scenario 2: User types `www.example.com/ausername` in their web browser.

Output: Result of rendering an `ejs` page server-side.

How can I achieve this in a very simple manner? I've tried:

```
app.get('/:username', function(req, res){
    res.render("user", { username: req.params.username });
});
```

This does work for `example.com/ausername` but when I type `example.com`, the request is again rendered by the above method, creating an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your static index.html in a 'public' folder in your project root and use the `express.static()` middleware to deliver that static page.

```
// Serve the static landing page at the root
// e.g. public/index.html => http://www.example.com/
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Serve the route
// e.g. http://www.example.com/test123
app.get('/:username', function(req, res){
    res.render("user", { username: req.params.username });
});
```

This will allow users to visit your static page at the root, and also visit your route when a value is supplied. See the [Express middleware documentation](http://expressjs.com/api#app.use) for more information.

Comment: The bigger question may be how to do this on parse.com - their docs indicate this is how their default routing should work but the OP hasn't been able to do that yet.